# Isomorphism of dual and regular representation of matrix algebra $A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory

In  [page 25, Theorem 2.7](http://www-math.mit.edu/~etingof/replect.pdf)  Etingof wrote

> $A \cong A^*$ as $A$-modules where $A^*:= Hom_k(A,k)$.

I know $A \hookrightarrow A$ by left action, $a \cdot x:= ax$ and $A \hookrightarrow A^*$ by $a \cdot l := la^{-1}$

> What is the explicit isomorphism here?

I thought the by making a choice of basis $\{ e_i \}$ the map $e_i \mapsto e'_i$, $\phi:A \rightarrow A'$, is an $A$-module isomoprhism.

But this doesn't seems to be the case, as suppose $a \cdot e_j = \sum t_{ij} e_i$, and $a^{-1} \cdot e_j = \sum t'_{ij} e_i$. Then

$$\phi( a \cdot e_i) (e_j) = t_{ij}, \text{ and } (a \cdot \phi(e_i))(e_j) = e'_i(a^{-1} e_j) = t'_{ij}.$$

So $\phi(a \dot e_i) \not= a \cdot \phi(e_i)$ in general. What's wrong?

Comment: Presumably when you write "$A \hookrightarrow A^*$" you mean the $A$-action on $A^*$? In which case the formula you wrote is not quite right, since elements of $A$ need not be invertible. You want transpose, not inverse.

Comment: Ah, that is right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is a matrix algebra over a commutative ring $R$, then the *trace* defines a linear map $A \to R$ given by $a \mapsto \mathrm{tr}(a)$. This induces a symmetric non-degenerate bilinear form $$(a,b)=\mathrm{tr}(ab)$$ on $A$, which allows you to identify $A$ with its dual as an $R$-module.

The $A$-action on $A^*$ is defined by the formula
$$(af)(b)=f(a^t b) \quad \hbox{for $a,b \in A$ and $f \in A^*$,}$$ where $a^t$ is the transpose of $a$. In order to make the identification of $A$ with $A^*$ intertwine left multiplication of $A$ on itself with this action, one uses the isomorphism
$$A \to A^*, \quad a \mapsto t_a=(b \mapsto \mathrm{tr}(a^t b)).$$